# How to access array created in Try Catch ?

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to access the array A outside the try function, but it says that the symbol cannot be found. How can I access the array A outside the try method ?

```
try {
        String filePath = "//Users/me/Desktop/list.txt";
        int N = 100000;
        int A[] = new int[N];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            A[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
    }
```

Comment: Put the use inside the try, or put the creation outside the try.

Comment: Google for "scope of variables". Basic topic, described in any good book or tutorial.

Comment: Create variable N  and array A before try block

Answer (score 2):

You're running into the variable's *scope*. You can only use the variable in the scope where you created it. It's the same situation, for example, when you create a variable inside of a method -- you cannot access that variable from another method.

You have two options: either use the variable in the same scope (the `try` block) or declare the variable outside of that scope.

**Option 1: the same scope**

```
try {
  ...
  int A[] = new int[N];
  ...
  // use A here only
} catch (IOException ioe) { ... }
// A is no longer available for use out here
```

**Option 2: declare it outside**

```
int A[] = new int [N];
try {
  ...
} catch( IOException ioe) { ... }
// use A here
// but be careful, you may not have initialized it if you threw and caught the exception!
```

Comment: As a general good practice, you should additionally limit try/catches to only including the lines of code that might actually throw a caught exception.

Comment: Yes, you can still use the array @lo1ngru. But be careful, it might not have had its values populated. So when you access `A[ idx ]`, it may be the default int value (0) instead of the value in the file that you were expecting. If your file contains zeroes, this may lead to some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

declare outside the block and allocate in the block:

```
int A[];

try {
        String filePath = "//Users/me/Desktop/list.txt";
        int N = 100000;
        A = new int[N];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            A[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
    }
```